# Getting this error using JSTL: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, properties, jstl, el

I don't understand why I am getting this error! I seem to have established the correct naming convention for the objects properties that are being called.

I am returning a list of objects to a .jsp page and am attempting to iterate over the list and access each properties attributes using `JSTL` like this:

```
<h2>Latest Testimonials</h2>
<c:forEach items="${testimonialList}" var="testimonial">
  <p><span class="quote">"${testimonial.getTestimonial}"</span> by ${testimonial.getAuthor</p>
</c:forEach>
```

This is the Testimonial object:

```
public class Testimonial {
    private String testimonial, author, date;

    // message get/set
    public String getTestimonial(){
        return testimonial;
    }
    public void setTestimonial(String testimonial){
        this.testimonial = testimonial;
    }

    // name get/set
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }

    // date get/set
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date){
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

The full error:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'getTestimonial' not
>   found on type uk.co.morleys.Testimonial

Why is it not finding the property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `get` here:

```
${testimonial.testimonial}
```

The get will automatically added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h2>Latest Testimonials</h2>
<c:forEach items="${testimonialList}" var="testimonial">
      <p><span class="quote">"${testimonial.testimonial}"</span> by ${testimonial.author</p>
</c:forEach>
```